# Can you instantiate an Element object AND define attributes simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, dom, formatting, element

This may seem like a silly question to some. The short background is; I am clinically diagnosed with OCD, I am thus very particular about the formatting and neatness of my code so I apologize in advance. This leads me to my question:

Is there a way in javascript to instantiate an object and define its attributes in a block? My goal might be somewhat analogous to how you'd see a JSON object/string

Here's some pseudocode/formatting:

```
var preElement = document.createElement('pre')
    .className = "nodeResults";
    .innerHTML = formattedResponse;
    .style = "blahblah";
    .anymoreAttributes = "stuff";
```

Inconsequential, I know. I just noticed I spent 30 minutes researching this instead of writing functional code. Downfall of OCD. SO please help me; Is this possible yes, or no?

Sincerely, 
    WastingTehTime

Comment: Possible, yes, but not like that. DOM functions don't return the element. You'd have to make your own helper.

Comment: Not out of the box. Just create a function that receives a string for the element type and an object for its properties. `create("pre", {className:"nodeResults", ... });`

Comment: ...or create one that accepts entire structures in a object format. That's what I do. The format I use is similar to JSONML. `["div", {id: "foo"}, ["span", {className: "bar"}]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not doable unless you write a class wrapper to handle this kind of formatting, or use the jQuery library.
jQuery example:

```
var preElement = $(document.createElement('pre'))
    .addClass("nodeResult")
    .html(formattedResponse)
    .css(jsonFormattedCSS)
```

jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/3h5kfv2j/

This can be implemented in vanilla javascript too, but you will need to find a library that does this or code it yourself.

Here is some sample code of a vanilla implementation I just made: http://jsfiddle.net/4n4w3uqr/

Comment: NICE! That answers that. Since I am already using jQuery this is great!